unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
While working on my game, my laptop crashed for some battery issue.
I restarted Unity and it asked me to resolve android depedendencies as it saw some changes. I resolved the dependencies by running the resolver.
Post that whenever I try to build a verison on to my ANdroid phone, it gives me this error.
I am using Unity 2023.1.7f1 and firebase_unity_sdk_11.8.1
Note before the crash happened I was able to build without any errors.
Build settings
----------error---------

Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:extractDeepLinksForAarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractDeepLinksForAarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:createFullJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:createFullJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata
Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions
92 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 88 up-to-date

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun ()

Yes, I did delete the app from the device and tried building. I get the same error. I see there is a duplicate issue ":launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets" however cant make out which class is a duplicate

I tried deleting resolved libraries, then Android resolver, getting the same issue.
